Is there a perfect hash function for a tree data structure with different kinds of nodes?
I am working on a tree structure that has the following structure (you can find the source code here)
type IRTerm
    = IRVar
    | IRFunc
    | IRApp
    | IRConst
    | IRNative
    | IRLetted
    | IRHoisted
    | IRError
    | IRForced
    | IRDelayed
    | IRConstr
    | IRCase;

where IRVar, IRConst, IRNative and IRError can be considered leaf nodes;
IRFunc, IRLetted, IRHoisted, IRForced and IRDelayed are nodes that always have only a single child;
an finally IRApp is a binary node, IRConstr may or not have many childs (always has a unsigned integer as an argument), and IRCase is guaranteed to have 2 or more childs.
I very often need to check for equality of sub-trees, so I decided to use hashes, trying to minimize iteration of the trees.
The previous method
I initially went for blake2b_128 implementation, not because I need it to be cryptographically secure, but just because I had it available.
Passing as input whatever data a leaf node had, or the concatenation of hashes of the child in case of non-leaf nodes. Always prefixed with a unique tag for the node, similar to THEX spec (from web archive)
(see example for IRVar or IRConst and examples for IRFunc, IRApp or IRCase)
using blake2b_128 I never experienced a collision, probably due to the 128-bit output.
However, there are important drawbacks to having a 128-bit output (in an implementation meant to work in javascript), mainly related to the fact that the most efficient way to store it is via a Uint8Array, the main drawbacks are:

It needs to be cloned to ensure no modifications are made, seriously impacting memory usage.
equality is an O(n) operation

the new method

DISCLAIMER
I am aware there are a lot of other ways to reduce memory usage, but addressing the usage of Uint8Array for hashes is something I will need to deal with anyway at some point

to address the two drawbacks explained above, I decided to move to a murmur2 implementation with a 64-bit output
this allows me to store the hash as a javascript number, which has the following benefits:

memory friendly for javascript runtimes
builtin equality (===)

Leaving the input data identical to the previous implementation (Unique node tag + child hash).
However, running some tests I quickly discovered some collisions;
an example can be seen in this tree where the tree hoised_precList hash collides with the hash of the sub-tree that during compilation replaces IRNative.z_comb
resulting in a tree hash colliding with the hash of the sub-tree, which is of course problematic.
I could change the hashing function to some other general purpose 64-bit output hash, but that will likely only move the collision somewhere else.
The real question
Is it even possible to design a perfect hash function for this data?
I understand that in order to design a perfect hash function the set needs to be finite.
To allow for that some assumptions can be introduced.
As an example is safe to assume that the data carried by an IRVar node will at most be a 32-bit integer.
For terms that have an indefinite number of children, we could introduce some merkelization so that they can act as if they always have 2 children like IRApp.
naive idea
one naive solution I though of would be to clear the first 4 bits of the resulting hash and replacing them with a unique identifier (or tag) of the node type; so that hashes of different node kinds would end up in "different buckets".
but I'm not sure it would be of any help, since in the example of colliding tree reported above, both root nodes are IRHoisted and both with IRFunc as direct child
Fallback question
In the event it is really not possible to come up with a perfect hash function for this structure; what can I implement to reduce the likelihood of collisions?

Although I always applaud people for looking into better algorithms rather than implementations, wouldn't the use of library functions or WebASM provide a big speedup in this occasion?

@MaartenBodewes the library this code is meant to work in made incredible effort to not use WASM due to degraded developer experience and issues in integration with other tools. That being said, even if we integrated a WASM solution, it would definitely help with hash calculations (js is horrible at that, I think we can all agree) it would still be problematic under the memory consumption point of view

The obvious approach would be to flatten the structure (that is, convert it into a byte string) and then apply an off-the-shelf perfect hash algorithm to the byte strings.

Another implementation note: as long as there is a canonical representation it is not required to have the entire structure available as a flattened structure, you can perform update / final over the structure by depth first tree walking and flattening each node. Of course the relatively high level (i.e. just terrible) SubtleCrypto API does not support update / final, so yeah, there goes hardware support I guess.,

hardware support would be nice but not required, I need to check for equality a lot of times, if I can compute a perfect hash once and compare that many times I don't care it is a little slow the first time I compute it
